# What is the difference between crontab -e and nano /etc/crontab?

Tags: cron

What is the difference between `crontab -e` and `nano /etc/crontab`? Do they point to the same thing?

Comment: Coincidentally, this was asked only days ago at Unix & Linux, where it had been asked before. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501372/

Answer (score 12):

The `crontab -e`  command will edit the crontab for your current user. This means that you do not need to include the username in the crontab line. Each user's crontab is stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`, under the user's name.

The format of a user specific crontab is:

```
# m h  dom mon dow  command
*   *   *   *   *   some_command
```

The `crontab -e` command will use whichever editor is set in your user's $EDITOR environment variable, which controls your default text editor for a variety of tasks. If that isn't set the first time you use the `crontab` command you'll be prompted to choose from a selection of available editors, `nano` is one of the choices on this list.

Editing `/etc/crontab` requires that you include a username that's running the command after the time setting part of the line.

The format of /etc/crontab is:

```
# m h dom mon dow user      command
*   *  *   *   *  someuser  some_command
```

Comment: doesn't `crontab -e` also do a syntax check ? AFAIK, that does not happen if you edit `/etc/crontab`

Comment: I think you're right. I wasn't sure though so didn't add it to the answer. I also think the crontab command is more highly recommended for general use, but again wanted to check before adding to the answer.

Comment: it also seems to be undocumented and not catch all sytnax errors

Comment: Another diff between `crontab -e` and `nano /etc/crontab` is that using the `crontab` command will use the current `$EDITOR` whereas the latter is using a specific editor (nano). The way the question was wondered suggested to me that OP didn't know this difference.

Comment: Very true @Scribblemacher, I'll add that in.

Comment: also, `crontab -e`will install the new crontab on save, while editing `/etc/crontab`will not. `cron` does reload it on its own, eventually

Comment: @RobertRiedl: And such reload has race conditions if it happens to occur at the same moment as a partially-rewritten file. The `crontab` command handles this safely with an atomic rename of a temp file.

Comment: @R.. Not if you edit with `sudoedit`, as you should always do when editing files as root. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The traditional system cron list is at /etc/crontab

The user crontabs are usually located at /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER.

Doing a 'crontab -e' automatically invokes the users editor and performs a basic validity/syntax check when you attempt to exit.

Any jobs scheduled using the user crontab are run under the users login id whereas the the system /etc/crontab has the capability to schedule jobs under any system userid listed in /etc/passwd.

If you want to play with fire, you can directly edit (vi/vim/nano/mcedit/...) your user crontab, bypassing any syntax check, by using for instance, "nano /var/spool/cron/crontabs/your-login-id" [ Or any userid if you are root or use sudo ]

For more detailed info, you might want to peruse the cron man pages ( 'man cron' )